# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: showed for every file after the restart of my VM

Tags: python, anaconda, errno

I have a program that opens a csv file and does some magic on it. Anyway on Friday it worked normally as it does, but today after I restarted my VM, no matter what .csv file I try to open it returns me this error :

**PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/admin.ab/export_1.csv'**

no matter in which directory the files is it still shows this same path.

Can someone explain why is this suddenly happening?

I already read the questions where it only happened to one file or they were trying to open path.
I tried different files and from different users. It always returns the same error only thing it changes is the name of the file - because different file was opened.

**EDIT**

Here is the code where it reads the file:

```
@app.route('/filtered_file', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def open_file():
'''Opens page with the file that was imported from the user.'''
if request.method == 'POST':
    #check if the post request has the file part
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return render_template('choose_file.html')

    #check if the right CSV file was selected
    file_upload = request.files['file']

    #check if the uploaded file a CSV file is
    if file_upload and allowed_file(file_upload.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file_upload.filename)
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        file_upload.save(file_path)
        file_to_filter = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=';', engine='python', encoding='utf-8-sig') #ISO-8859-1
        table1 = filter_csv(file_to_filter)
        table2 = table1.to_html(classes='my_class" id = "my_id')
        os.remove(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return render_template('filtered_file.html', data=table2)

return render_template('choose_file.html')
```

Part II :

```
#only be able to import the csv file and nothing else
allowed_extensions = set(['csv'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    '''Function used to check if the file imported is equal=csv'''
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in 
    allowed_extensions
```

Comment: if `no matter in which directory the files is it still shows this same path.` then `'C:/Users/admin.ab/export_1.csv'` path is somewhere hardcoded. Anyway no code → no idea

Comment: @rzlvmp I am confused as to why is it happening now and didn't show up sometime before. I added code where it reads the file

Comment: what is value of `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']`?

Comment: @rzlvmp this : **app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'C:/Users/admin.ab/'**

Comment: In this case I don't understand meaning of `no matter in which directory the files is it still shows this same path`. You set this path in `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']`, so Flask trying to upload in this folder. The code looking correct, so maybe here are OS problems? (Is admin.ab exists? Is Flask running under admin.ab user? Is Flask running with `As Administrator` privileges?)

Comment: @rzlvmp you were right... the problem was that a colleague of mine started the program and doing so removed all permissions for the rest of us. I just restarted it on my user and now it works! (Yes , admin.ab exists - that is my user, but when I start the program on my user everyone can work on the program) thank you for helping me debug this

Answer (score 0):

I have some pointer your can try. There could be many reasons this error can come up but few common and popular reasons are following

1. File or File's parent folder permission.

   - Check for files (you .py files as well as .csv files) UGO permissions
   - Check for parent folders UGO permission
2. Your file/folder could be improperly in open mode by some other python program.
3. In case, if you have multithreading enabled then case 2 can happen as well
4. Internal package/pip update issue(a bugged update). Rare cases but happens.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it seems I had a different os problem, it resolved when I restarted the program with my user that enables right access.

Comment: @miwa_p - Cool ! This comes under mentioned case 1. If you files had UGO permission opened for all users then this would have never occurred !